# multi-step or nested queries (in R RMySQL or RSQLite)?

Tags: sql, r, rmysql, rsqlite

after getting some feedback to my original question, I have edited this question to include additional detail and to be more specific about what I am still stuck on...

I am using 'R' version 4.3.2 to run a script (text file named ExportUtility.R) that allows me to export data from a database into a .CSV file.  I run this export utility from within a .BAT file with the following command...

```
"C:\Program Files\R\R-4.3.2\bin\x64\r.exe" CMD BATCH ExportUtility.R
```

The key parts of the the ExportUtility.R field seem to be the following: First, establishing a connection to an ODBC data source...

```
source_conn <- DBI::dbConnect(odbc(), dsn="LabelTraxx_64_Lum")
```

Next, executing the query (where I can set sql_query to whatever SQL I want...

```
data <- dbGetQuery(source_conn, sql_query)
```

Next, writing the results of the query to a .CSV file (where I can set filename to whatever I want)...

```
write.table(data, file=filename, append=FALSE, quote=TRUE, sep=",", col.names=TRUE, row.names=FALSE)
```

The exact SQL Query I am having trouble with is as follows:

```
WITH T1 AS (SELECT Number, OrderDate FROM Ticket) SELECT Number, OrderDate FROM T1
```

When I try to run this query, I get the following error..

```
Error: nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp:1769: 08004: Server rejected the connection:
Failed to parse statement.
 
<SQL> 'WITH T1 AS (SELECT Number, OrderDate FROM Ticket) SELECT T1.Number, T1.OrderDate FROM T1 '
Execution halted
```

When I run just the "Inner" query below, I get no error, and I get the expected data in my .csv file.

```
SELECT Number, OrderDate FROM Ticket
```

If anyone can help me figure out what is wrong with the query in which I use the WITH clause, I would greatly appreciate it.

Thanks in advance,
Paul

Comment: Please include the following: OS; version of MySQL remote server (`"SELECT version()"`, perhaps); version of R and R's packages `DBI` and `odbc`; if not windows, version of underlying OS packages related to ODBC and MySQL (if debian-like, `dpkg -l | grep -E 'odbc|mysql'` might be enough).

Comment: My OS is Windows 10 Pro 64 bit.  SELECT version() gave me the same Failed to parse statement / Execution halted error I got when I tried to run the statement in which I had the WITH clause.  I now think that my ExportUtility.R script may not be using MySQL.  The reason I think this is I commented out the following library() lines and all of my previously working queries still work.  Commented out #  RMySQL, RODBC, RSQLite, sqldf.  Not commented out: DBI, utils, odbc, purr, dplyr, tibble, dplyr, tibble, dplyr.  Do you know how I can check the versions of DBI and odbc? thank you

Comment: You should be able to know the database type via one of two methods: (1) if you are specifying `driver="..."` in your call to `dbConnect`, then that should clearly indicate which driver you are using and therefore a very good idea on the remote DBMS; or (2) a named DSN, so open the ODBC controller (probably but not definitely the 64-bit) and look for the specific name and see which driver is being used. I'm not running windows atm so I cannot verify this, but give those two a gander and lmk what you find.

Comment: I have a hard time following this, though, since afaict CTEs are supported in [mysql](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/with.html) (and mariadb), [sql server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16), [sqlite](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_with.html), [postgres](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html), etc. I don't work with Access files, but I've seen several posts that suggest CTEs are not supported with them ... but I don't know for certain, hope somebody else can help here.

Answer (score 1):

CTE (common table expression), perhaps?

```
with StepOneResults as (
  SELECT Table1.GroupField, Count(Table1.CountField)
  FROM Tabel1
  GROUP BY Table1.GroupField
)
SELECT StepOneResults.GroupField, Table2.SomeOtherField
FROM StepOneResults
  LEFT JOIN Table2 ON Table2.GroupField = StepOneResults.GroupField
```

Comment: Thank you r2evans for you reply.  The CTE technique using a 'with' statement sounds like it would be perfect for what I am trying to accomplish.  Unfortunately, I think it may not be supported in the 'R' environment I am working in.  I'd like to write a more detailed follow-up question to explain why I think this.  To properly explain, I think I might need more characters and formatting flexibility than this 'comment' feature in stack overflow seems to afford.  Is there a better way (or place) I can post a follow-up question?  (short of clicking on "Answer Your Question")

Comment: I don't understand: if the query is just a string, how are you constrained in your R environment such that you can form at string starting with `SELECT` but you cannot form a string string with `WITH`? I run this type of query daily in R.

Comment: Said differently ... `query <- "with StepOneResults (...) select StepOneResults.GroupField ..." ; mydata <- DBI::dbGetQuery(con, query);` works (newlines are optional here).

Comment: I have a text file with a .R extension that was provided by the supplier of a database application my company uses, with instructions on how to edit this file to create my own custom queries that pull data from the underlying database.  When I edit this file to run a query that I want, I run it using a .BAT file that calls "C:\Program Files\R\R-4.3.2\bin\x64\r.exe" CMD BATCH ExportUtility.R.  I don't understand all the code in this .R file, but I can tell that for the query strings I build, it does execute them by calling    data <- dbGetQuery(source_conn, sql_query)

Comment: I tried writing the simplest query I could come up that uses the WITH clause, and I get a 'Failed to parse statement' error.  Not fully understanding everything that this .R script is doing, I'm not sure whether this error is purely from R, or if it is something peculiar to how this .R script is implemented.  The query I tried is   WITH T1 AS (SELECT Number, OrderDate FROM Ticket) SELECT Number, OrderDate FROM T1  .... I know the inner query SELECT Number, OrderDate FROM Ticket  does work.  Please let me know if you see anything wrong with my syntax in my WITH statement

Comment: Edit your question and put the full query and its error, phase.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like your SQL CTE is not well formed - the final element is simply:

```
OrderDate FROM T1
```

You could try changing it to:

```
SELECT OrderDate FROM T1
```

If that doesn't solve your problem, you might find it easier to debug your SQL if you took it out of your R code and put it in it's own file. Most editors recognize SQL and highlight the syntax etc. The [sqlhelper](https://majerr.github.io/sqlhelper) package is designed to execute SQL written this way (full disclosure: I wrote it).